# Delay in changing Google Spreadsheet content via Google apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, timedelay

I am totally new to Google-apps-script and this may be very poor question 
 
I am making a basic setup using google forms and google apps script 
From the responses of form I change my content in Google Spreadsheet accordingly 
For example my query from form needed 10000 records to be selected and produced in whole another spreadsheet 
I just wanted to know that is there some kind of delay introduced when I set and get values of any cell of spreadsheet on such a large scale? If so on what it depends and how as a programmer can I remove or optimize them?
Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 6):

The [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) article by Google is the primary reference for this. The most important advice is to minimize the number of calls to spreadsheet methods by batching operations. So, select a range that contains all the records you need, get them all at once with `getValues`, process without further interaction with the spreadsheet, and output the result using `setValues`.

If you follow this advice, 10000 records is still a reasonable amount of data to process by a script.